# Using Facebook Graph API 2.2 to get like and share count

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on updating project from old FQL to graph api 2.2 and i dont have idea how to get likes count on specific link, their documentation is not very transparent for me(i'm beginer). I believe it shoud be something like this: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/?id={myURL}/{some fields like like_count}` but i have no clue how to do it right using graph API. I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the docs are quite clear I think:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/url#read

There is NO like count on the `/?id={url}` endpoint! A sample call would be

```
GET /?id=http://mashable.com/2015/02/17/10-minute-rule/
```

Response:

```
{
  "og_object": {
    "id": "664547577004455", 
    "description": "Three tips for making the 10-minute rule work for you.", 
    "title": "A 10-minute timer could revolutionize your productivity", 
    "type": "article", 
    "updated_time": "2015-02-17T13:55:11+0000", 
    "url": "http://mashable.com/2015/02/17/10-minute-rule/"
  }, 
  "share": {
    "comment_count": 0, 
    "share_count": 180
  }, 
  "id": "http://mashable.com/2015/02/17/10-minute-rule/"
}
```

If you just want the share count, use

```
GET /?fields=id,share&id=http://mashable.com/2015/02/17/10-minute-rule/
```

Response:

```
{
  "id": "http://mashable.com/2015/02/17/10-minute-rule/", 
  "share": {
    "comment_count": 0, 
    "share_count": 180
  }
}
```

Comment: ok so there is any way to get, all the info that i could from fql? for example

`$fql = "SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, ";
            $fql .= "total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM ";
            $fql .= "link_stat WHERE url = '" . $url . "'";` Thanks for anwser!

Comment: Damn you facebook! But anyway, you helped me alot Tobi!

Comment: Normally, the OpenGraph object should have a `likes` edge, but for the example it shows no data: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=664547577004455%3Fmetadata%3D1&version=v2.2&